# Fixed height header and scrollable div in variable height div

Tags: css, layout

Consider this demo layout:

```
<div style="height: 100%">
  <div style="height: 100px;">Header</div>
  <div style="overflow: scroll; height: auto;">
      ...content...
  </div>
</div>
```

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/119xLvwu/))

The inner content div should consume up as much as height as possible (i.e. 100% - 100px) and scroll its content. Is that possible?

(Browser compatibility isn't an issue.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the document's height to 100% with these styles:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

You can then set the height of the overflow div specifically with:

```
height: calc(100% - 100px);
```

[**Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/5nt87vq3/)

---

The more modern way to accomplish this is by making the container a [**flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), with these styles:

```
height: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

Then use these styles for the header:

```
height: 100px;
flex: none;
```

And simply `overflow: scroll;` for the scrollable content.

[**Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/22aL7hoz/)

Comment: In the flex example, did you mean to apply `flex:none` to the scroll element? In the header, it's overriding the `height:100px`.

Comment: I applied `flex:none` to the header, so that it would maintain the 100px height.  That way, the scroll div would expand to take the rest of the space.

Comment: `flex: none` overrides `height: 100px` with `height: auto`. For the scroll div to expand the rest of the space it just needs `flex: 1`.

Comment: @Michael_B, actually, both methods accomplish the same thing.  I like using `flex: none;`, because that implies that the element should maintain its defined dimensions.

Comment: `flex: none` is short for `flex-grow: 0`, `flex-shrink: 0`, `flex-basis: auto`. Coming after `height: 100px` in a column-direction container is the same as putting `height: auto`, which overrides the first rule and the header is no longer 100px tall.

Comment: I may be confused, but I don't see any difference between our methods.  Compare my Fiddle 2 with https://jsfiddle.net/22aL7hoz/1/

Comment: The header is supposed to be a fixed `height: 100px`. It's not in both fiddles.

Comment: @Michael_B, what browser are you using?  In Chrome, it's always 100px.  Compare https://jsfiddle.net/22aL7hoz/4/ to https://jsfiddle.net/22aL7hoz/3/

Comment: The behavior of this layout is variable depending on browser and scroll content size. I still don't see the use of `flex: none`, but I'm having trouble developing a reliable example.

Comment: Putting `height: auto` after `height: 100px` doesn't make sense to me. But it does, in fact, work in your examples.

Comment: I understand the confusion.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis#Values.  `flex-basis: auto` has changed over time, but it now means, "look at my width or height property."

Comment: Even better, thanks.  To me, it's more intuitive to tell sized elements to "not" flex rather than to tell unsized elements to flex.